# How to use drag and drop to upload files in database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to upload one file on server as well as want to save the uploaded file in the database. I want to use only one drag and drop operation. I don't want to use any button click event. Kindly give me suggestion how can i do this and if possible provide me code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this jquery file-upload plugin

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

--Nitin

Comment: i don't want any upload button; but this contains upload button for uploading file

Comment: There are lot of options & events, you can hide the plugin's buttons at the time of `$(document).ready()` event of the page.  https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options